# Is it possible to get to the local directory of my in the Google Cloud shell?

Tags: google-app-engine, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to run a Tensorflow object classifier in Google Cloud. The problem is that in the command  for training, ask for a local path for a cloud.yaml file. The code taken from the Google Cloud Documentation instruccions is the following:

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training object_detection_`date +%s` \
    --job-dir=gs://${TRAIN_DIR} \
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz            \
    --module-name object_detection.train \
    --region us-central1 \
    --config **${PATH_TO_LOCAL_YAML_FILE}** \
    -- \
    --train_dir=gs://${TRAIN_DIR} \
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH}
```

Comment: Post the error message also to get more clarity

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting the Cloud.yaml file in the root directory of my Google cloud. It is actually possible to call a path in that directory from the Google cloud terminal.